# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 362

Tags: javascript, json

I wrote a JS code:

```js
window.scraping = JSON.parse('"' + tab_url + '"' + ":" + JSON.stringify(scraping));
```

where `tab_url` is:

```js
'"https://www.google.com/search?ei=UFd7XvKqG9DwaIauhLgB&q=integrate+discord+chat+in+atom&oq=integrate+discord+chat+in+atom&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l3j0i22i10i30j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l3.205903.213924..214423...0.4..0.509.1961.0j1j0j1j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i10.DB2bC6vf4pE&ved=0ahUKEwjykr3I2LXoAhVQOBoKHQYXARcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5":{"title":"","text":"","ranking_word":{},"a":[],"img":[],"html":""}'
```

and where `scraping` is:

```js
var scraping = {
                "title": "",
                "text": "",
                "ranking_word": {},
                "a": [],
                "img": [],
                "html": ""
              }
```

The code return me a error:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 362
```

I don't understand why the `:` is denied...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to embed scraping object in tab_url.

Try running this snippet.

```js
let scraping = {
                "title": "",
                "text": "",
                "ranking_word": {},
                "a": [],
                "img": [],
                "html": ""
};
let tab_url = `{"https://www.google.com/search?ei=UFd7XvKqG9DwaIauhLgB&q=integrate+discord+chat+in+atom&oq=integrate+discord+chat+in+atom&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l3j0i22i10i30j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l3.205903.213924..214423...0.4..0.509.1961.0j1j0j1j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i10.DB2bC6vf4pE&ved=0ahUKEwjykr3I2LXoAhVQOBoKHQYXARcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5":${JSON.stringify(scraping)}}`;
console.log(JSON.parse(tab_url));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```